# $project with $cond in mongodb not returning field value

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to use $project condition vise, but mongodb giving me the **Unexpected Identifier** error. Below is my code, how i am using `$cond` and `$project

```
$cond: { if: {req.query._id}, then: {"$project" : { projectName : 1 }}, else: {"$project" : { projectName : 1,developers:1}} }
```

Can anyone please correct, what is wrong in above query?

Comment: will be necessary inster $con into object? like "{ $cond: {...}}"

Comment: I did with, what you explain. But not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with below syntax:

```
fieldName:
{
   $cond: { if: (condition), then: "$fieldName", else: false }
},
```